# How does Excel handle the h:mm:ss format?

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time, cell-format

I have the number `0.00082788917980126` which once converted to `h:mm:ss` format gives me `0:01:12`, and I need to understand how as I need to perform similar formatting outside Excel, hence my question:

**How does Excel convert a number into the h:mm:ss format?**

Comment: I'm a little lost (sorry) - are you able to explain what you mean by outside Excel? Do you just want to understand the logic how to convert a number into a DateTime for your own programming or similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Source: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm

> Excel stores dates and times as a number representing the number of days since 1900-Jan-0, plus a fractional portion of a 24 hour day:   **`ddddd.tttttt`**. This is called a serial date, or serial date-time.
>
> **Times**
>   The fractional portion of the number, **`ttttt`**, represents the fractional portion of a 24 hour day.  For example, 6:00 AM is stored as 0.25, or 25% of a 24 hour day.  Similarly, 6PM is stored at 0.75,  or 75% percent of a 24 hour day.
>
> **Dates**
>   The integer portion of the number, **`ddddd`**, represents the number of days since 1900-Jan-0.  For example, the date 19-Jan-2000 is stored as 36,544, since 36,544 days have passed since 1900-Jan-0.  The number 1 represents 1900-Jan-1.

#### Example calculation in Excel

```
hours of a day              = 24
minutes of a day            = 60
seconds of a day            = 60        
total seconds of a day      = 24 * 60 * 60 = 86400

your time as serial date    = 0.00082788917980126       
your seconds since midnight = 86400 * 0.00082788917980126 = 71.5296251348289

hours      =ROUNDDOWN( 71.5296251348289 / 3600, 0 )    = 0      
minutes    =ROUNDDOWN( 71.5296251348289 / 60, 0 )      = 1      
seconds    =ROUND( MOD( 71.5296251348289, 60 ), 0 )    = 12     
your formatted time                                    = 00:01:12
```

- You can expand the calculation to milliseconds and more